# jQuery UI datetimepicker change date & time format showed in text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

jQuery: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

After user change time, text field showed as 20120625 122900.

I would like to change the format for 20120625122900, without space between date and time.

Can anyone provide a good way to show the format which I want?

Comment: what if you keep seperator: '' blank.

Answer (score 6):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){  

       // $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        $("#datepicker").datetimepicker(
                {
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    timeFormat: 'hhmm',
                    showSecond: false,
                    dateFormat:'ymmdd',
                    separator: ''
                });


        //$('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
            //altField: "#alt_example_4_alt",
            //altFieldTimeOnly: false ,
            //timeFormat: 'hhmm' ,
            //dateFormat:'ymmdd'
        //});

    });


</script>
```

Comment: Add single qoutes instead double and test --- Check this http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/date-formats.html

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this line in the [github repo](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/blob/master/src/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js#L94).

If you change that for `''` it should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot! After I change that, it's display the format which I want.